# Equivalent of `using` aliases for `template`s

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, using

C++11 added alias templates such as:

```
 template<typename T> using identity = T;
 template<bool b, typename T = void> using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<b, T>::type;
```

These are much easier to use than the old `template` type maps that give you the return value in a `::type` field because even if your type arguments are dependent on the local context, you don't need to inform the compiler that the result is a type.

In effect, you hoist the `typename` from the location of use to the `using` alias.

Is there anything equivalent that can be used to get rid of produced extraneous `template`s?

Suppose you had a metafunction whose output was a class or alias template instead of a type.  The current method is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct my_meta {
  template<typename U>
  using Template = identity<U>;
};

template<typename T>
struct my_meta {
  template<typename U>
  using Template = int;
};
```

which we can then use like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename my_meta<T>::template Template<U>
do_stuff( U&& ) { return {}; }
```

That extra `template` keyword in the return type exists to disambiguate the return value of my meta function is what I want to eliminate.

Is there any way to indicate to the compiler that the result of a metacomputation is another alias or class template in C++11 or C++1y, without using the `template` keyword at the location of invocation?

Ie:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
my_meta_template<T><U>
do_stuff( U&& ) { return {}; }
```

or even

```
template<template<typename> class Template>
void do_more_stuff() {}

template<typename T>
void do_stuff() {
  // syntax I want: just produce an alias or class template directly:
  do_more_stuff< my_meta_template<T> >();
  // vs what I find is required: the disambiguator:
  do_more_stuff< my_meta<T>::template Template >();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way I know to remove `template` is made simple warper that will do it for you:

```
template<typename Meta, typename U>
using apply = typename Meta::template Template<U>;
```

and every where you previously used `template<typename> class Template` replace it with `typename Meta`.

```
template<typename Meta>
void do_more_stuff()
{
    apply<Meta, int>::func(); //=== Meta::template Template<int>::func();
}

template<typename T>
void do_stuff() {
  do_more_stuff< my_meta<T> >();
  do_more_stuff< my_meta<T> >();
};
```

Comment: This is good for nested types but doesn't help for other contexts such as calling a member function of a dependent type: `t.template f<A>()`

Comment: if `f` is fixed it can be solved in similar way: `template<class U, class T, class... Args> auto call_f(T _this, Args&&... a) -> decltype(_this.template f<U>(std::forward(a)...)) { return _this.template f<U>(std::forward(a)...);}`