# template template alias to a nested template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-aliases

Template aliases are very convenient in simplifying types like `typename F <T>::type` to just `F <T>`, where `T` and `type` are types.

I would like to do the same for templates like `F <T>::map`, i.e., simplify them to `F <T>`, where `T` and `map` are template structs or aliases.

For instance, consider the following definitions:

```
template <bool B>
using expr = std::integral_constant <bool, B>;

template <bool B>
using _not = expr <!B>;

template <template <typename> class F>
struct neg_f
{
    template <typename T>
    using map = _not <F <T>{}>;
};

template <typename T>
pred = expr < /* ... T ... */ >;  // e.g., pred = expr <true>;

template <template <typename> class F>
struct fun;
```

Now the following works:

```
fun <neg_f <pred>::map>
```

This would be much more convenient, but it fails:

```
template <template <typename> class F>
using neg = neg_f <F>::map;

fun <neg <pred> >
```

(It also fails with `neg = neg_f <F>::template map`, even if `map` is defined as a struct). It appears that the definition of `neg` above would rather have to be like a "template template alias"

```
template <template <typename> class F>
template <typename T>
using neg = neg_f <F>::template map <T>;
```

but apparently there is no such thing.

So, is there any solution or should I stay with `neg_f <pred>::map` ?

Comment: I asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356487/equivalent-of-using-aliases-for-templates and there doesn't seem to be a good answer.

Comment: Indeed, the last part of your question is very similar or the same. Thanks.

Comment: Your using of spaces before `<` makes everything extremely unpleasant to read, for some reasons.

Comment: @Jeffrey I am sorry for this. On the other hand, I would find `template<template<typename> class F>` extremely unpleasant; `template< template< typename > class F >` as well. It's pretty standard using space before parentheses, e.g. `if (x < 0)`, so spaces before `<` look natural to me.

Comment: I do not understand what those neg_f and other stuff represent, if you described that somewhat better perhaps we could come up with a solution

Comment: Also: I don't see how that can compile with {} (initializing an object in a declaration)

Comment: @DavidKernin My apologies, `neg_f` is supposed to *negate* a type predicate, that is, `neg_f<F>::map` is another type predicate that, when applied to a type `T`, gives the complement of whatever `F<T>` gives. I didn't explain because its definition is so simple and because it's just a example, it's not essential to the problem (I could equally use a `foo`-like example).

Comment: @DavidKernin On `_not <F <T>{}>`: `F` is a type predicate, i.e. `F<T>` is `std::integral_constant<bool,B>` for some `B` as shown by the definitions. Meaning that `F<T>{}` is an object of literal type that is implicitly converted to `bool`, in turn used as non-type template parameter for `_not`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

At first consider using `typename` keyword to state that this is a nested type no matter if one is a type (e.g. struct, class, etc), template type, typedef or alias.

Alias [specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) requires you to use a *type-id* to specify a previously defined type. In this particular case correct using of *type-id* will look like this:

```
template< template<typename> class F, class T>
using neg_v2 = typename neg_f<F>::template map<T>;

// or

struct foo {};
template< template<typename> class F>
using neg_v1 = typename neg_f<F>::template map<foo>;
```

What you try to do originally is to use *template-name* `neg_f<F>::map`as a *type-id*. This is not correct.

Probably you want to deduce somehow the `T` parameter from `F` to be used at `template map<T>` but this is not applicable to your final use-case `fun<neg<pred>>` where `T` is not resolved.

Comment: So the error list shows the root cause. See my edits to the answer.

Comment: I didn't try to use template-name neg_f<F>::map as a type-id. You did that.

Comment: here is your try to use a template-name `neg_f <F>::map` as a type-id ;) `template <template <typename> class F>
using neg = neg_f <F>::map`

Comment: This was hypothetical code to illustrate the question, if you read the entire sentence. Anyway, I removed the downvote.