# Is it possible to create a template alias?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, type-alias

Consider the following code:

```
template< template< typename ... > class ... Ts >
struct unite
{
    template< typename ... T >
    struct type
        : Ts< T ... > ...
    { };
};

// This does not work as ::type does not name a type, but a template:

// template< template< typename ... > class ... Ts >
// using unite_t = typename unite< Ts ... >::type;

template< typename > struct debug_none {};
template< typename > struct debug_cout {};

template< typename ... > struct raise_demangled {};
template< typename ... > struct raise_specialized {};

template< typename, typename = int > struct match_default {};

template< template< typename ... > class Control >
void f()
{}

int main()
{
    f< unite< debug_none, raise_demangled, match_default >::type >();

    // Is there any way to create something like unite_t which works like this:

    // f< unite_t< debug_none, raise_demangled, match_default > >();
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43af981698cafec5)

Question: **Is there any way to create some kind of "template alias" similar to a type alias?** (see `unite_t` in the above example)

Comment: So, question: I remembered as I wrote that I asked this exact question before.  Should I close my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356487/equivalent-of-using-aliases-for-templates as a duplicate of this one?  Or vice versa?  :)

Comment: @Yakk Although your question is quite similar and in the same area, I don't think it is really a duplicate, as you tried to get rid of the `template` keyword in a different place. If a solution for one *would* exists, it *might* solve the other problem as well - but it seems there is no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot.

`using` can "return" a type, or a variable.  It cannot "return" a `template`.  There are no similar mechanisms elsewhere.

You can do something vaguely useful by taking the convention that all templates are not templates, but rather classes with a `template<?>using apply=?;` alias inside them (and while we are at it, constants are `std::integral_constants<T,?>`, and pointers are `pointer_constant<T*,?>`).

Now everything is a class.  `template`s become just *kinds* of classes (with a `::apply<?...>`.

Applying a bundle of types to such a template would be done via:

```
template<class Z, class...Ts>
using apply_t = Z::template apply<Ts...>;
```

So with a "native" template `Z`, you'd do `Z<Ts...>`.  With these "indirect" templates, you'd do `apply_t<Z, Ts...>`.

With this convention, a template `using` alias can return an indirect template.  If the rest of your code follows the convention of always calling `apply_t` to apply a template, and you indirect-ize all other templates you write, we are done.

This is ugly.

Comment: Is there a proposal to fix this?

Comment: @Brian not that I know of.  The need to have such aliases is questionable, as only relatively advanced usage of C++ requires it, so maybe nobody has bothered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll probably mark it as "accepted" soon - the "No, you cannot"-part :) Sadly the suggested alternative/work-around can not really be used in my case as it would make the interface (which is visible towards the user) even more complicated/ugly. I am actually considering to drop this idea instead of confusing users.